# How to count Steps although phone without built in pedometer

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to count user steps, iam using this code and it works fine

```
    SensorManager sManager;
    Sensor stepSensor;

        sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        stepSensor = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);

           sManager.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        float[] values = event.values;
        int value = -1;

        if (values.length > 0) {
            value = (int) values[0];
        }


        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
steps++;  }
            }
        }
    }
```

but in some devices

```
stepSensor = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
```

return null , i searched about that and found that this device may not have  pedometer

so how can i detect steps in that case?

Comment: You can use a Google Fit API, but for that you also have to implement Google Auth. But you can read about it. This API uses not only Step Detection sensors but also accelerometer, gyroscope, gps and others. It also has Sensors API for realtime reding of the steps data. But, really, you better check it by yourself, maybe this API do not meet your needs

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

First import `    implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:sensorstep:1.4.2@aar'

and follow my repository:

https://gitlab.com/jonathan123vazna/podometersteeps

Good Code.
`